# HtmlElementView does not scroll with the listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am developing flutter web application. The list will show ads adsense as one of the items using HtmlElementView. The problem is that when the mouse is over the HtmlElementView, the scrolling stops and the list does not scroll further.

This is a list item with ads:

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    item_1,
    item_2,
    item_3,
    SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      child: HtmlElementView(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        viewType: 'iframeElement',
      ),
    ),

    ...

    item_n,
  ]
)
```

How do I make the HtmlElementView scroll with the listview?